# Contact duplicate rule condition is not working on Lead convert (Apex)

Tags: apex, contact, lead-conversion, duplicate-management, conditional

I have written custom Lead Convert apex class and vf page.

I have a duplicate rule "active" on contact.

**The issue i am facing -** When i try to convert a lead, contact duplicate rule's condition is not working/bypass and show me an error

> ConvertLead failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
> DUPLICATES_DETECTED, A duplicated contact is found in the system,
> please update the existing contact.: []

Condition i have on contact duplicate rule -

If **Contact Lead Source** not equal to **Company XYZ**

The matching rule i have used in my contact duplicate rule -

```
(Contact: FirstNameFUZZY: FIRST NAMEMatchBlank = TRUE) AND (Contact: LastNameFUZZY: LAST NAMEMatchBlank = TRUE) AND (Contact: AccountFUZZY: COMPANY NAMEMatchBlank = TRUE)
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong here?